# SQLite Manager - Copy table to another .sqlite database

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, sqlitemanager

Working on my first iOS App with SQLite database. In Project I have 2 Database, in which First Database is having only one table and the another one is working as a main database. I want to merge those databases into one (the Second one), by copy the table from first database to second database. The First database Table contains more than 32K records. So, I want to copy the entire table with Data.

**I want to achieve this using SQLManager AddOn of firefox.**

Any Idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of SQLManager, You can simply do this with one command line:

```
$ echo '.dump tablename' | sqlite3 sourcedb | sqlite3 destdb
```

Answer (score 2):

Export the required table contents in to an excel sheet in sqlite manager and then import the excel file in the target database.

you can see the controls for import and export in sqlite manager itself. 
I hope this may help u, since I used it.